# How to properly architect an Amazon AWS ecosystem for use as a public application service provider (ASP)?

Tags: networking, architecture, amazon-web-services

I have an application that could be ported to something like a WordPress plugin, but some issues arise out of that.  The algorithms that allow the system to do what it does would be fully exposed, and available for all to copy, etc.  Modification and improvements would be simple from the community, however.

On the other hand, instead of adding all the existing functionality into the plugin, the plugin (at time of download) could be linked to a central server, where an account would be created, user management and data dissemination would occur from that central server on a per-account basis.

This brings into play a greater requirement for network architecture, and ensuring proper scaling schemes are in place.

The current .Net application runs with one SQL Server and IIS and a Windows Server running, and currently generates about 50,000 page views a month running on a single Amazon AWS m1.large instance, and needs to be bumped up to a more powerful instance.  Obviously I plan to split this into two servers as revenue increases

All data access is performed through a single data access service and is well architected for a 1..* situation - data access is not bound to one website.

My question is this:  To offer data access as a service to the masses, what are the pieces of the AWS puzzle that I need to put in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS components you should be using are most likely:

- Route53
- Elastic Load Balancer
- Auto-Scaling Groups
- Cloud Watch
- Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)
- EC2
- Amazon Machine Image + bootstrapping
- Dynamo DB
- Elastic Block Store (EBS)
- EBS Snapshots to S3 potentially with rules to move them to Glacier
- Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles
- SNS (I'm thinking of cost-based alarms here)

Here's a bit of a brain dump about a solution:

Route53 can handle your DNS. Use an Elastic Load Balancer to direct traffic to your EC2 web servers. Place the web servers in a Virtual Private Cloud with subnets in multiple Availability Zones. Use Auto-Scaling to scale capacity as demand changes. Probably have some "pilot light" reserved EC2 instances and consider using on-demand or light / medium reserved instances to meet spikes in demand (depending on your specific situation). Create your own Amazon Machine Image which is capable of bootstrapping itself with the latest copy of your application. Configure IIS to use Dynamo DB for session state (this will allow you to scale your web server layer without users suffering session loss). Authentication to Dynamo DB (and any other AWS infrastructure) should be via an IAM role that you provided when provisioning the EC2 instance.

For the DB it gets complicated, the outline would be multiple EBS volumes - OS, Database, Database Backups. You might want to consider using provisioned IOPS for the database volume. Use mirroring to have an additional SQL DB in another availability zone. The web server connection strings would also include information about the failover DB server. Perform database backups to an EBS volume specifically for that purpose. Use a powershell script to kickoff an EBS snapshot after the DB backup to file had been performed. Configure the S3 bucket to archive snapshots after x amount to time to Glacier. Some additional thought may be required here with respect to how incremental snapshots are managed.

There's always going to be more, and this is fairly high level, but its hopefully provided you with some pointers in the right direction. :)